# Difference between 'array[:] = something' and 'array = something'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know they practically do the same thing, but if you were to lets say do something like...

```
curpop = this_other_ndarray
i = 0;
while i<20:
    curpop[:] = select(curpop, parameter, parameter1)
    stuff
    more stuff
    curpop[:] = some_stuff_I_did
    i += 1;
```

So the above code is just saying, before I enter a generational loop I am going to take an initial generation of populations from 'this other ndarray'.
Then I am planning on changing that array over and over and everytime I restart the loop I will only select some from itself but I will declare that as what it is equal to now. Is this okay to do in Python3?

Is the declaration of 
`'array[:] = some of it self'`
versus
`'array = some of itself'`
different at all?

Comment: Yes, completely different. One assigns one object to a name, the other uses slice-based assignment to mutate an object

Answer (score 1):

These are two totally different things.

The first is simple assignment.

```
foo = bar
```

This assignment statement merely says that the name on the left-hand side now refers to the same object as the name on the right-hand side.  These statements do not modify either object.

Objects are neither created nor *necessarily* destroyed. If you lose the last name of an object, however, you will have lost the object. The CPython runtime uses reference counting as a memory management strategy, and will automatically reclaim objects that have a zero reference count.

In Python, variables act simply like object names that you can create, destroy, and change what they reference. Think of them like name-tags.

Now, a statement like:

```
foo[:] = bar
```

Is *actually* a method call. It can be translated to:

```
foo.__setitem__(slice(None, None, None), bar)
```

Observe:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
...         print("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
...
>>> class Bar: pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> foo[:] = bar
Key: slice(None, None, None) Value: <__main__.Bar object at 0x104aa5c50>
```

So, really, the *type* of the objects control the ultimate effects of this statement. In the case of `numpy.ndarray` objects, slice-based assignment works similarly to `list` slice based assignment in that it mutates the array object in-place, with a few more caveats like broadcasting to throw into the mix. See the relevant docs:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays

Answer (score -1):

In many cases

```
curpop[:]= iterable_value_as_tuple_string_dictionary_and_list_etc
```

do the same thing as

```
curpop=iterable_value_as_tuple_string_dictionary_and_list_etc
```

of course assign a string first or at any step will remove the ability in the next steps to use `[:]` to assign something again

note that

```
 curpop[:]= notiterable_value  != curpop=notiterable_value
```

as the first assign `notiterable_value` to each element of `curpop` and the second assign the value `notiterable_value` to `curpop` itself